# GitLab upload npm package with dynamic package.json informations

Tags: npm, gitlab, registry

I want to upload an npm package to a local GitLab instance.
According to the GitLab documentation, it is necessary to provide the package name with the namespace and to include the entry publishConfig in the package.json.
As soon as I do this manually and create a valid .npmrc file, the upload works.

Is there a possibility to add this information dynamically to the package.json via the yml file for the CI? All the necessary information is available as predefined environment variables.

Comment: Do you try to publish [NPM packages in your project’s Package Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/) ?

Comment: yes i want to publish. But I would like to have the scope and the publishConfig entry written dynamically via the CI in the package.json. I was hoping there would be standard tools here. But I haven't found anything. I am currently solving my problem with a small NodeJS script, which I execute shortly before publish.